$\exists$ a open set $G$ such that $m^{*}(G \backslash E) <\epsilon$ implies $\exists$ a closed set $F$ such that $m^{*}(E \backslash F)<\epsilon$
I know that $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ is Lebesgue measurable, it is equivalent to a proposition that  $\forall \epsilon>0$, there exists an open set $G \supset E$ such that $m^{*}(G \backslash E) <\epsilon$.
However, without invoking the measurability of $E$, and other statements involving $F_{\sigma}$ set and $G_{\delta}$ set, how can we directly prove the following proposition:
If $E \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a subset, and let $m^{*}$ be the Lebesgue outer measure, then $\forall \epsilon>0$ , there exists a open set $G \supset E$ such that $m^{*}(G \backslash E) <\epsilon$ implies that $\forall \epsilon>0$ , there exists a closed set $F \subset E$ such that $m^{*}(E \backslash F)<\epsilon$ .
I can see that $G \supset E$ is an open set, then $G^{c}$ is a closed set, and we have $G^{c}\subset E^{c}$. I think the closed set $F$ that is contained in $E$ should be obtained mysteriously from this $G^{c}$. However, I don't know how to construct it. Any help on this? Thanks

This is not true unless $E$ is Lebesgue measurable.
